# What are the exact dimensions of a B-2 Spirit?

Tags: b-2

I want to make a 3D model of a B-2 Spirit bomber. However I'd like to know the excact dimensions of it so that I can make it at least somewhat accurate.
I'd like to know the lenghts of the following red lines(each straight line separately):
[image: B-2 with requested dimensions]

Comment: I doubt you will find an official source for these. I'd look for a B-2 on google maps/Earth and use the distance measuring tool.

Comment: I am working on getting some info from the official, unclassified documentation. But I'd appreciate some help from others.

Comment: Have you asked DOD about that?

Comment: Did you even consider what I suggested? I found a B-2 on google maps in less than 5 seconds google search

Comment: Could you please send a link? I can't find it.

Comment: @MichalŠtein https://www.google.com/maps/@38.7250446,-93.5602627,145m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt you will find an official source for these. Luckily, we have google maps.

Using this example from Whiteman AFB (https://www.google.com/maps/@38.7250446,-93.5602627,145m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en) and distance measuring tool we get the following lengths:

[image]

1 - ~4.65 m (~15.24 ft)

2 - ~3.69 m (~12.10 ft)

3 - ~7.83 m (~25.69 ft)

4 - ~10.71 m (~35.13 ft)

5 - ~4.58 m (~15.04 ft)

6 - ~31.52 m (~103.40 ft)

The rest you can get from the published dimensions (height, length, wingspan), as [an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_B-2_Spirit#Specifications_(B-2A_Block_30)).

Comment: Nice.  You seem like the type who might be thinking about joining the upcoming Area 51 invasion?

Comment: I live in Europe but I can give support.

Comment: Just like in the story about the B-2s unveiling, where some journalists (allegedly) overflew the site to get pictures of the planform and tail, which the military was not keen to show.

Comment: What's the other aircraft next to the bomber? A T-38 Talon? There are two more on the other side of the hangers as well.

Comment: @DarthPaghius Correct