# Airplanes in static display at Whiteman AFB

Tags: aircraft-identification, us-air-force

After reading the [post about B-2 sizing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/66947/28868), I spend a couple of minutes on Google Maps looking at airplanes on the Whiteman AFB.

On runways, I think there are one B-2 Spirit, 3 T-38 Talon, and one AH-64 Apache.

On static display, I have spotted an F-111, one B-52 (north of the base), one A-10, one T-38, one B-47, and one B-29 at the south gate.

But there are also 3 more fighters at [this location](https://www.google.com/maps/@38.724129,-93.5679019,145m/data=!3m1!1e3).

[image: the 3 fighters from Google Maps]

Center one seems to be an F-22 Raptor.

What are the two other ones? And is there any more static airplanes spread over this base?

Comment: That's not an F-22 -- the wings are the wrong shape, for one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

F-100, F-15, and F-4.  There is no F-22. The thing that looks like a brown nose cone on the F-100 appears to actually be the long, nose-mounted pitot boom, painted a light color, with its shadow visible just above it in the photo, all blurred together to give the impression of a much wider object.  It's clear from the shadow of the fuselage that the fuselage truncates abruptly in front, as per the air intake of an F-100.

All these three types were used by the US Air Force.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_F-100_Super_Sabre#United_States) the F-100 on display at this base is a D model, number 55-3667.

[Aerial Visuals](http://aerialvisuals.ca/LocationDossier.php?Serial=2949) has information about it, the neighboring aircraft, and other aircraft on display on the base.

[This facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/131BW/posts/793717530663611)  describes these three aircraft being moved to their current location, with closer photos of the F-100.

[This webpage of military aircraft on display in Missouri](http://rickmorganbooks.com/military-display-aircraft-in-missouri.html) also has photos of these 3 aircraft before they were moved to Whiteman AFB (see the "St. Louis, Lambert Field" section), as well as other aircraft on display at Whiteman AFB.

These three types were all flown by the Missouri Air National Guard 131st Fighter Wing, now the 131st Bomb Wing- a unit currently based at Whiteman AFB.  Read more about it on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/131st_Bomb_Wing).

Comment: The AeroVisuals website is confusing- in one place, based on the coordinates, sites "a", " b", and " c" appear to refer to the 3 planes on display side-by-side, but in another place it says site c is not accessable to the public but sites a and b are.  Looks like the website could use a little help!

Comment: Now I'm at my laptop and can see the photo a bit sharper than I could on my phone-- changed answer just a tiny bit to better explain the apparent "nosecone" of top plane.

Comment: "based on the coordinates, sites "a", " b", and " c" appear to refer to the 3 planes on display side-by-side" -- because they are each about one second apart in terms of latitude.

Comment: which is about 100 feet

Comment: Considering that it was not initially clear that the brown thing at the front of the top plane was not a nose cone, here are some of the observations that initially steered me away from F-11: large size.  Canopy far behind front of "nose cone".  Wing fairly tapered (small chord near tips) rather than closer to constant-chord.  Wingtips not obviously rounded.   Side intakes appeared small on first glance and entirely absent on closer look.   Just in case you were curious...  At one point F-101 even crossed my mind-- seemed a good fit for the relationship between the canopy and the more

Comment: At one point F-101 even crossed my mind-- seemed a good fit for the relationship between the canopy and the more forward portions including the apparent "nose cone"-- but of course the jet exhaust arrangement was all wrong.  Finally I realized there was no nose cone in front.

Comment: Last 2 links found by simply googling "F-100 Whiteman"

Answer (score 2):

It's not an F-22.

From left to right:

Maybe [F-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_F-11_Tiger) (though I'd be surprised if there were F-11s with the "european" camo),

[F-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F-15_Eagle),

[F-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F-4_Phantom_II)

Comment: Indeed for the F15, I found it in the meantime on the [wiki page of the base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whiteman_Air_Force_Base#Modern_era): moved from Lambert-St. Louis International Airport.

Comment: Looking at 3-view on wikipedia I would say F-11 wings are closer to constant-chord-- wings of this plane are too narrow near tips for F-11, also F-11 wingtips are more rounded, and intakes should appear bigger.  Don't know what it is.  Also maybe too big for F-11.

Comment: Ok got it now--

Comment: Also F-11 wasn't used by USAF as far as I know!

Comment: Yeah, Navy jet gate guarding an *Air Force* base?... you'd sooner find a MiG...